# how to affect foreach items style every item alone

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-core

i used "foreach" statement to access all items of IEnumerable and present it in details page ....and i want to make float property of each item different from the other items ....so i used  jQuery to affects on each item....but when i run the code all items became with the same direction.....how to affects on each item alone and make its direction of first to right and second to left and third to right ...etc?

here is html code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TimeLines)
{
    <section id="timeline">
        <article>
            <div class="inner">
                <span class="date">
                    <span class="day">@item.EventDate</span>
                </span>
                <h2>@item.Title</h2>
                <p>@item.Body</p>
                <div class="form-group row col-lg-12">
                    @*<div class="button_cont row col-lg-6" align="center"><a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="TimeLines" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="example_c" noopener">Edit</a></div>*@
                    <div class="button_cont row col-lg-6" align="center"><a asp-controller="TimeLines" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="cursor:pointer;" class="example_c" id="del">حذف</a></div>
                    <div class="button_cont row col-lg-6" align="center"><a asp-controller="TimeLines" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="cursor:pointer;" class="example_c">تعديل</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
}
```

and jQuery code:

```
<script>
        $('section article').each(function (i, element) {
            $(element).find('div.inner').css('float', 'right');
            element = element.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
            $(element).find('div.inner').css('float', 'left');

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You could loop with an index, and conditionally add the style/class with `index % 2 == 0`. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22373172/3717691). Otherwise you can perhaps do it with [CSS entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items).

Comment: can you make it easy for me and show me the full code to be clear for me>>>if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work, cause you set the next sibling to `left`, but in the next iteration this sibling still get `float: right`.

As Jeppe mentioned in his comment you could use an index like this:

```
var index = 0;
$('section article').each(function (i, element) {
    var setFloat = (index % 2 === 0) ? "right" : "left";
  $(element).find('div.inner').css('float', setFloat);
  index++;
});
```

EDIT:

The CSS solution from dfliess was on the right way, but since there is only one `div.inner` in every `article tag` it will not work this way, cause every `article` has only one `div.inner child`.

If you still want a CSS only solution, you could do something like this:

```
section:nth-of-type(odd) article div.inner {
    float: left;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) article div.inner {
    float: right;
}
```

This one gives the styles to the `div.inner` of every odd/even section.
Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jg6ht1ro/

Comment: You're welcome :). I updatet my answer, if you still want a css only solution

Comment: I think it is cleaner with CSS. `.css(...)` applies the styling on the `style` attribute,  which is a lot harder to maintain IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with @tawin answer or I would suggest to use css selector :nth-child

Try with something like:

```css
section article div.inner:nth-child(odd) {
    float:left;
}

section article div.inner:nth-child(even) {
    float:right;
}
```

More info on https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child