# Getting iterator of MVC IEnumerable EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I am using MVC to display a table of checkbox options.  I know that I can call `EditorFor()` on a collection of objects and it will produce a list of them by looping through the collection and outputting HTML based on each item's editor template.  My question is, is there a way of accessing the iterator of this loop within the editor template, so that I can start a new row of the table every, say, 3 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, naming the items the correct thing for your model binding is important.  See this article:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I especially found helpful the part describing naming the complex object array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Brad Wilson link in the following post, should be what you are after.

[How to create custom editor/display templates in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497183/how-to-create-custom-editor-display-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I already have a template; I'm trying to get it to work with the iterator from the automatic MVC loop started by using an EditorFor a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you can use:

```
  List<string> items = new List<string>();
  items.Add("Item 1");
  items.Add("Item 2");
  items.Add("Item 3");

  var result = items.Select((item, index) => new { index, item });
```

and then `if(index % 3 == 0) { ... }`

OR

[In ASP.NET MVC, is there a way to get the loop index when using EditorTemplates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669704/in-asp-net-mvc-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-loop-index-when-using-editortemplates)